# Halfplane region intersection anomaly

Tags: regions

When I intersect a square with the halfplane above the line through two points 
$\{c,d\}$, I get a different result from intersecting the square with the halfplane above the same two points in the other order, $\{d,c\}$.

---

[image]

---

In the figure, $\{c,d\}$ is the red segment. The first intersection is incorrect, the second is correct.
When I truncate the coordinates for $\{c,d\}$ to two decimal places, both yield the correct intersection.

Anyone know what's going on? Version 11.1.1.0. My code is below.

```
{c1, c2, c3, c4} = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}; 
{c, d} = {{0.5517683063965324`, 0}, {0, 0.10423352813687581`}};
s = Region[Polygon[{c1, c2, c3, c4}]];
h3cd = Region[HalfPlane[{c, d}, {0, 1}]];
h3dc = Region[HalfPlane[{d, c}, {0, 1}]];

r23cd = RegionIntersection[
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[s],
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[h3cd]
   ];
Print[Show[Region[r23cd, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}], 
   Graphics[{Red, Line[{c, d}]}], ImageSize -> Tiny]];
r23dc = RegionIntersection[
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[s],
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[h3dc]
   ];
Print[Show[Region[r23dc, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}], 
   Graphics[{Red, Line[{c, d}]}], ImageSize -> Tiny]];
```

(Pardon the variable names; extracted from longer code.)

Comment: Might be useful if someone could verify the code behaves the same on their system, to eliminate possible OpSys or processor causes...